# ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, macos, dockerfile

I was trying to create image in docker and got that error.
There are 2 mistakes:

```
ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.7
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to parse /Users/Vlad/.docker/.token_seed: unexpected end of JSON input
```

[image]

I want to mention that I'm using someones else laptop for personal reasons, so I don't know the passwords, but you can still suggest solutions requiring password use.

I tried deleting .json file as they say in guides and renaming Dockerfile to fix the second error and it didn't work.

Tried googling for the similar errors, but I didn't find any solutions for myself.

Answer (score 0):

docker pull python:3.7 fixed it.